# can we use select * when we do for max(cgpa) with nested query

Tags: mysql, oracle, group-by, max

```
select * 
from student_database 
where BTECH_CGPA in (SELECT max(BTECH_CGPA) 
             FROM student_database 
          group by SPECILIZATION);
```

This gives 48 rows as selected, but it should be 29 rows without duplicates of max cgpa to other department.

Example :

```
       BTECH_CGPA            SPECILIZATION

           9.55              CSE A 
           9.79              CSE B
           9.55              CSE B (again)
```

Please can anyone help me out

Comment: Is this oracle or mysql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 48 rows this mean that in student_database there more rows that macth for the result of the in clause ..(because the group by in subselect assure that you get only the distinct result)

In this case if you want  a distinct result in the main select you can't use * but you must explicitally set the column you need with the distinct clause .. eg:

```
select distinct col1, col2
from student_database 
where BTECH_CGPA in (SELECT max(BTECH_CGPA) 
         FROM student_database 
      group by SPECILIZATION);
```

Comment: explain better .. you want all the column ... and then 48 rows or you want 29 rows and for this you must exclude  the column with more that a result ?

Comment: 29 columns or 29 rows?   in your question 29 rows in your comments 29 column .. .. and you ask me if i understand your problem ... ? be clear  please

Comment: 29 rows ... and this question is not duplicate and that is not the solution

Comment: Is not possibile that your subselect return more then 29 rows (or the number or distinct specilization) .. could be that you select returning 48 rows because there are more rows that macth the same BTECH_CGPA  ..